# buggy start up on repaired upgrade from 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, 16.04, dbus

I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Xenial 16.04 using the software updater, but unfortunately the upgrade froze when it was installing what appeared to be some fonts. 
As it was not responding for a long time and I couldn't do anything else, I forced a hard reboot. This took me straight to a terminal (no GUI), where I ran:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Which ran and fixed a great deal of things, but it encountered two errors configuring the packages 'cgmanager' and 'systemd-shim'. 
I rebooted and logged in (this time the gui loaded) to run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

which finished without any further problems.

Since then my startup sequence seems all over the place. It looks like the boot sequence is restarting at one point and it looks very unstable. 
There is no text output but my screen is turning on and off, resizing a box with the ubuntu purple/black background, the ubuntu loading splash screen only appears very shortly. 
It then loads the login screen but with the default ubuntu background image, but then switches to my background image, as if the login screen is reloaded.

Which leads me to believe I didn't fully upgrade, or at least that there are some config issues.

in my /var/log/syslog I found that the right kernel was loaded and 'quiet splash' parameters are set:

```
Aug  8 10:22:35 PC83 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-31-generic (buildd@lgw01-16) (gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) ) #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-31.50-generic 4.4.13)
Aug  8 10:22:35 PC83 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic root=UUID=8966e632-6b98-48ad-9ebb-46f41e62e711 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

I had some errors in my syslog however:

```
Aug  8 10:31:55 PC83 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1011.
Aug  8 10:31:55 PC83 org.ayatana.bamf[4161]: bamfdaemon start/running, process 4219
Aug  8 10:31:55 PC83 org.a11y.Bus[4161]: ** (process:4230): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided b
y any .service files
Aug  8 10:31:55 PC83 org.a11y.Bus[4161]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Aug  8 10:31:55 PC83 org.a11y.Bus[4161]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Aug  8 10:31:55 PC83 org.a11y.atspi.Registry[4235]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Aug  8 10:31:56 PC83 systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Aug  8 10:31:56 PC83 rtkit-daemon[2824]: Successfully made thread 4418 of process 4418 (n/a) owned by '1001' high priority at nice level -11.
Aug  8 10:31:56 PC83 rtkit-daemon[2824]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 colord[2143]: (colord:2143): Cd-WARNING **: failed to get session [pid 4415]: No such device or address
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 rtkit-daemon[2824]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 rtkit-daemon[2824]: Successfully made thread 4437 of process 4418 (n/a) owned by '1001' RT at priority 5.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 rtkit-daemon[2824]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 rtkit-daemon[2824]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 rtkit-daemon[2824]: Successfully made thread 4439 of process 4418 (n/a) owned by '1001' RT at priority 5.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 rtkit-daemon[2824]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 rtkit-daemon[2824]: Successfully made thread 4441 of process 4441 (n/a) owned by '1001' high priority at nice level -11.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 rtkit-daemon[2824]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 pulseaudio[4441]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 dbus[1967]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service'
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 dbus[1967]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 org.gnome.ScreenSaver[4161]: ** (gnome-screensaver:4358): WARNING **: Couldn't get presence status: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 gnome-session[4301]: gnome-session-binary[4301]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file gnome-user-share.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 gnome-session-binary[4301]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file gnome-user-share.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 gnome-session[4301]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1001/keyring/ssh
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 gnome-session[4301]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1001/keyring/ssh
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 gnome-session[4301]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1001/keyring/ssh
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 gnome-session-binary[4301]: Entering running state
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 gnome-session[4301]: (process:4474): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Unable to get watcher name 'org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher'
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 gnome-session[4301]: (process:4474): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Name Lost
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 dbus[1967]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' unit='udisks2.service'
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 systemd[1]: Starting Disk Manager...
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 udisksd[4528]: udisks daemon version 2.1.7 starting
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 gnome-session[4301]: (gnome-software:4470): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Fa
iled: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 gnome-session[4301]: (gnome-software:4470): Gs-WARNING **: Failed to create permission org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Fa
iled: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
Aug  8 10:31:57 PC83 dbus[1967]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' (using servicehelper)
Aug  8 10:31:58 PC83 dbus[1967]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2'
Aug  8 10:31:58 PC83 systemd[1]: Started Disk Manager.
Aug  8 10:31:58 PC83 udisksd[4528]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Aug  8 10:31:58 PC83 org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor[4161]: Volume monitor alive
Aug  8 10:31:58 PC83 gnome-session[4301]: Starting Dropbox...Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
Aug  8 10:31:59 PC83 org.freedesktop.fwupd[1967]: (fwupd:4539): Fu-WARNING **: Failed to coldplug: UEFI firmware updating not supported
Aug  8 10:31:59 PC83 dbus[1967]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Aug  8 10:31:59 PC83 org.gnome.ScreenSaver[4161]: ** Message: Lost the name, shutting down.
```

Specifically:

```
Aug  8 10:31:55 PC83 org.a11y.Bus[4161]: ** (process:4230): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided b
y any .service files
```

and

```
Aug  8 10:31:59 PC83 org.freedesktop.fwupd[1967]: (fwupd:4539): Fu-WARNING **: Failed to coldplug: UEFI firmware updating not supported
Aug  8 10:31:59 PC83 dbus[1967]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
```

It looks like the org.freedesktop.DBus is not initiated properly. 
How could I resolve the bus properly and start it?

What else could I try to find the origin of the startup issue or any other configuration conflicts?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Update:

So in the end the whole thing became to unstable for me to work on, so I decided to bite the bullet and reinstall Ubuntu. However, this did **not** solve this issue. 
The start sequence is still all bouncy and flicks on different background images. Which leads me to believe it might be a BIOS issue, not loading the OS properly or so? 
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having the same issue after a botched upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04. Here is a video I made: https://youtu.be/0pHVeeHbE9I

Comment: @nbv4 my start sequence looks a bit different. I don't see any text actually, just a lot of different shades of grey (oh man..)